# reposition UILabel in UIView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uilabel

I have four `UILabel` added programmatically to a `UIView`, and need each of those `UILabel` to be hidden based on some if condition.

Also,

1. Once the `UILabel` is hidden, decrease the height of the `UIView` based on the hidden `UILabel's` height.
2. Reposition the remaining `UILabels` to fit inside the `UIView` after each `UILabel` turns to hidden state.

I have the following bit of code that I can share with -

```
if alphaChars != [] {       //my if condition   
      lettersValidation.removeFromSuperview()     //removing one UILabel
          
      if(alphaCharBool == false){
          tipsViewSection.frame.size.height = tipsViewSection.frame.size.height - 100       //decreased height of the UIView
          alphaCharBool = true
         }
            
      }
      else {
         self.tipsViewSection.addSubview(lettersValidation)     //add UILabel back to the UIView because if condition failed
          alphaCharBool = true
            
      }
}
```

Likewise, I am implementing same structure for other `UILabels`. Could someone help improve this code satisfying the conditions mentioned in the beginning of my question?

Comment: Not really sure I understand your condition. But you should really try to use Constraints (Autolayout) instead of changing the frame. If you setup the constraints in Interface Builder (IB) you can create an outlet property for it: @IBOutlet var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint! and then change its "constant" value to control its height

Comment: Use autolayout and if you want to hide any label - set its height to Zero, all other Labels will automatically reposition.

Comment: Dharmendra, I am creating my UILabels not on storyboard, but doing it programatically

Comment: on ViewDidLoad(), I added autolayout constraint for the label, and setting it to zero in my if condition. But the other labels are not repositioned automatically